# Upload enterprise application on ABM

Tags: ios, enterprise, apple-business-manager

How to Upload enterprise application on ABM (Apple Business Manager) account?

I got .ipa created with Apple Enterprise Account, but not sure how to upload it to Apple Business Account.

Comment: You don't. Apple Business Manager can be used to make volume purchase program purchases of App Store apps, including private apps that a developer has made available to your organisation through App Store connect. An enterprise app is either distributed via an MDM server or via a web page directly to the devices.

Comment: @Paulw11 If we upload an Enterprise application to MDM and MDM is linked to ABM, then will the enterprise application be available in ABM?

Comment: No.  Enterprise applications are entirely outside of the App Store system.  Apple Business Manager only lets you purchase apps from the App Store